# Spring Boot. Изменить конфигурацию логирования без перекомпиляции

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

В проекте, для логирования используется logback, в ресурсах есть его xml конфиг "по умолчанию". Возможно ли положить рядом с jar или в правильную папку файл с конфигурацией, подходящей для стенда и перезапустить приложение, чтобы оно подтянуло новый конфиг, без перекомпиляции?

Comment: можно запустить jar с другими переменными окружения, с помощью их можно указать путь к конфиг файлу, который будет на конкретном стенде

Comment: Нашел параметр запуска -DLogback.configurationFile

Файл конфига лежит в папке config, я запускаю локально, вот таким образом:
java -jar target/app.jar -DLogback.configurationFile=config/logback-spring.xml

Но конфигурация не подхватилась

Comment: я точно не помню как резолвятся пути, попробуйте для начала указать абсолютный путь